# position sidebar in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get this sidebar in the right handside instead of the lefthandside, what should I do? I have tried almost everything, but I cannot really turn it in my head :-/ Everytime I think I am on the correct track, something is not working.

[SIdebar](http://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <!-- Sidebar -->
  <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
    <ul class="sidebar-nav">
      <li class="sidebar-brand">
        <a href="#">
        Start Bootstrap
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Shortcuts</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Overview</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Events</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->
  <!-- Page Content -->
  <div id="contentcontainer">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 bg-danger">
          <h1>Simple Sidebar</h1>
          <p>This templaate has a respThis tThis template has a responte has a respTate has a respThis tThis template has a responhis tThis template has a responsive menu toggling system. emplate has a responsive menu toggling system. onsive menu toggling system. The menu will appear collapsed on smaller screens, and will appear non-collapsed on larger screens. When toggled using the button below, the menu will appear/disappear. On small screens, the page content will be pushed off canvas.</p>
          <p>Make surThis template has a responsive menu toggling system. e to keep all page content wThis template has a responsive menu toggling system. ithin the <code>#page-content-wrapper</code>.</p>
          <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
    /*!
 * Start Bootstrap - Simple Sidebar HTML Template (http://startbootstrap.com)
 * Code licensed under the Apache License v2.0.
 * For details, see http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.
 */

/* Toggle Styles */

#wrapper {
     padding-right: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
     padding-right: 0;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    right:0;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #000;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 15px;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: 0;
}

/* Sidebar Styles */

.sidebar-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
    text-indent: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
    height: 65px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 60px;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: none;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    #wrapper {
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled {
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 180px;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 0;
    }

    #page-content-wrapper {
        padding: 20px;
        position: relative;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
        position: relative;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}
```

JS:

```
<!-- Menu Toggle Script -->
    <script>
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Post HTML also here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can following way:

Change `padding-right: 250px;` from `padding-left: 0;` in `#wrapper` and in toggle.

```
#wrapper.toggled {
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

`#sidebar-wrapper` should be  `right: 0;` instead of `left: 250px;`.

Then change `margin-right: 250px;` in `#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper`.

And change to

```
@media(min-width:768px) {
    #wrapper {
        padding-left: 0;
    }
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6062jtm8/)**

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But how do I make the content dynamic like this: http://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/

Comment: @Julie24 Dynamic means? it's dynamic it is wrapped when open and close sidebar. check working fiddle

Comment: but there is nothing called left: 0; in #sidebar-wrapper

Comment: @Julie24 you have not change `padding-left: 250px;` to `padding-left: 0;` of `#wrapper` in `@media(min-width:768px) `

Comment: @Julie24 and `padding-right: 250px;` in normal `#wrapper`.

Comment: ah yes coures. THe content area is filling the whole page now. But the problem is that it is opisite now. THe orginal where the bar is in the left side: http://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/ , the content area is dynamic, where as the code as it is now, the sidebar is just going in and out, without the content is moving.

Comment: @Julie24 Can you give you updated code here in stackoverflow. I can not view in youtube

Comment: @Julie24 Still you have not change in `padding-right: 250px;` in  `#wrapper` Check first css. `#wrapper {
     padding-right: 250px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}`

Comment: It is working like a new born baby now :) Thank you a lot

Comment: @Julie24 glad to help. New born baby. Hahaha :D

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 @media (min-width: 768px) {
      #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 250px;
        left: auto;
        right: 0;
        margin-left: 0;
      }
      #page-content-wrapper{
        margin-left: -250px;
      }
    }
```

Comment: cool, the bar is actually on the right side now. But the contene window is not streched all the way to the left side now

Comment: ah one more thing. The content window is stuck now. When you toogle the menu button, the content expands: http://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/
In my code it is stuck now

Comment: That time add a class for content wrapper and style with margin-left:0 ;